# How can I systematically duplicate the entries in a column into another column in Excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste

In Excel I have a larger list of values in column A:

```
John
Jim
Joanne
Jenny
```

Is there a way in excel to copy paste those values into Column B, but creating N duplicates of each entry?
For example with N=3 the result should look like:

```
John
John
John
Jim
Jim
Jim
Joanne
Joanne
Joanne
Jenny
Jenny
Jenny
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not literally copy and paste as far as I know but fairly easy with a spill formula in Excel 365:

```
=INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*3,1,0),3)+1)
```

[image]

In earlier versions of Excel you could do this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)+1)
```

or (to avoid zeros on blank cells)

```
=IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:A)*3,"",INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)+1))
```

and pull it down.

Comment: Hi, thanks, tried out first example and it works nicely. However, I needed to replace commas with semicolons. So my formula looks like this

=INDEX(A$1:A$19;QUOTIENT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A$1:A$19)*3;1;0);3)+1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub NameCopy()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    r = 1
    n = 3
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
        For i = 1 To n
            Cells(r, 2).Value = c.Value
            r = r + 1
        Next i
    Next c
End Sub
```